# Pass data to OnItemClickListener?

Tags: java, android, event-handling

```
DataAccess data = new DataAccess(db);
List<String> countries = data.getCountries();

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, countries));

ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
      int position, long id) {

      // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

How can I pass and access `data` variable from inside the `onItemClick` method?

Answer (score 4):

make `data` `final` and you should be able to reference it from within onItemClick with `data`

Answer (score 4):

```
final DataAccess data = new DataAccess(db);


lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
      int position, long id) {

        List<String> countries = data.getCountries();
   }
}
```

There is a reason why we do this. When you invoke "new OnItemClickListener()" you are essentially creating an anonymous inner class. The bytecode that gets generated do not actually translate into an inner class, the JVM has no idea about this inner class.

The Inner class files are translated into separate class files which has a combination of the Outer Class file and Inner Class File separated by the "$" sign. Since this case it is Anonymous, integers are used to identify the inner class.

```
OuterClass$1.class
```

In the above scenario, when you create a variable in the Outer class, then inner class will have no idea about it. 
However when you mark it as final, the inner class (actual class file) will get a hidden variable within it with a reference to the outer class variable.

```
data$data
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain regarding the anonymous inner class, etc.